# SELECT returning aggregate answer from one table based on weightings in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with data that looks like this. The `col1` and `col2` are values and the index is based off the `nodeID`, `Date`, and `Hour`

```
nodeID    col1    col2    Date      Hour
  1       8       4      1/1/2010     1
  2       2       7      1/1/2010     1
  3       1       2      1/1/2010     1
  4       6       3      1/1/2010     1     
 ...     ...     ...      ...        ...
  1       2       2      1/1/2013     1
  2       3       4      1/1/2013     1
  3       7       1      1/1/2013     1
  4       5       1      1/1/2013     1
```

I have another table that has different weightings based on the day (not the hour) and it will look like this except there will be many names in addition to 'foo'.  Each name will be in more than one row and each of those rows will have a weighting factor of nodeIDs.

Each name for a particular day will have a weighting that adds up to one.

```
name       nodeID    weighting        Date
foo          1         .6            1/1/2010
foo          2         .4            1/1/2010
foo          1         .6            1/1/2013
foo          2         .3            1/1/2013
foo          3         .1            1/1/2013
...         ...        ...           ...
```

I need to query for the data from all the names with weighted averages of the parent data in table 1.

For example

```
name    col1     col2     Datecol    Hour
foo      5.6      5.2      1/1/2010    1
foo      2.8      2.5      1/1/2013    1
```

Note that the weightings changed from 1/1/2010 to 1/1/2013 and even included an extra `nodeID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    name, 
    sum(col1*weighting) as weightedCol1, 
    sum(col2*weighting) as weightedCol2,
    n.date, 
    [hour]
from
    nodes n
    inner join weights w
        on w.nodeid = n.nodeid
        and w.date = n.date
group by 
    name, n.date, [hour]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know join was so flexible I thought I was going to have to do some pivoting or unpivoting.  Anyway, doing this, I find that the weightedcol1,2 are double what they should be.  Any idea why this would be the case?  Its simple enough to put /2 at the end but I don't want to do that unless I know it is going to be consistent.  Also, I forgot one thing that makes this a little trickier.  The weights table doesn't have values everyday.  How do I  use the most recent day from weights that is <= n.date.  For instance if my weight ex had 12/21/2012 instead of 1/1/2013?

Comment: Based on the schema you provided, you shouldn't be getting double weights. Are you sure there's only one set of weights per name per date? And only one set of node values per nodeID per hour?

Comment: Are you able to alter your schema at all?

Comment: If you can alter your schema, I would change your weights table from an explicit date to a FromDate and ToDate range, and then change the join to "n.date between w.fromdate and w.todate"

Comment: You're right I accidentally had double weightings in my table.  As for the date thing I'll either do what you suggested or start a new question since its a different problem than the main question.